# MYSQL / MariaDB Trigger - After update

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mariadb

I have 2 similar tables. TableB is containing part of Part A record.

```
tableA -

+---------+------------+-------+
|      id | username   | team  |
+---------+------------+-------+
|       1 | Peter      | W     |
+---------+------------+-------+
|       2 | Sam        | W     |
+---------+------------+-------+
|       3 | Mary       | W     |
+---------+------------+-------+


tableB -
+---------+------------+-------+
|      id | username   | team  |
+---------+------------+-------+
|       3 | Mary       | W     |
+---------+------------+-------+
```

Now I want to update some record in tableB:

```
UPDATE tableB 
SET team = 'K' WHERE username = 'Mary';
```

How can I use trigger to sync team records in Table A for **Mary** only?

I am drafting the Trigger like below:

```
DELIMITER $$  
  
CREATE TRIGGER after_update_tableB
AFTER UPDATE  
ON tableB FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
    UPDATE tableA
    SET tableA.team = new.team 
    WHERE tableA.id= new.id;
    
END $$  


DELIMITER ;
```

I think new.id cannot locate to '3'? Because it hasn't changed?

Comment: *I think new.id cannot locate to '3'? Because it hasn't changed?* It will be successfully "located". The row, not the column, is updated, and `id` is a part of it even when this column's new value is equal to old one.

Comment: @Akina Thanks! Got it, will try.